# The geodata server is down for maintenance

Tags: r, geo

I've been trying to automate the download of GADM data (level 0) using R. But I keep on getting this error

The geodata server is down for maintenance.
It is expected to be back online on April 13, 2023.

Here's the code that I used:

```r
# Download GADM data for each country
gadm_list <- lapplyy(iso3, function(x){
  tryCatch({
    geodata::gadm(country = x, level = 0, path = tempdir())
    }, error = function(e){
      message(paste("Skipping country due to error:", e$message))
      return(NULL)
    })
})
```

I tried downloading it manually and loading it in R. Someone has tried it (automated) and worked so I'm guessing that it might be the something about region where you are currently accessing it?

Comment: Hi Gerald, this is a good question, but it could be improved in a couple of ways: (1) Please include code as text, not a picture (I have fixed this for you) (2) Please use a reproducible example; in this case by providing a small example of what `iso3` could be.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an ongoing issue with the GeoData package: See this Github issue for details:

https://github.com/rspatial/geodata/issues/50

It might be worth installing the development version of the package from Github. Try running: `devtools::install_github("rspatial/geodata")` and running your code again.

A (possibly time consuming) workaround could be to download the data you need directly from [gadm.org](https://gadm.org/)

Comment: Hi Hat! Saw the thread regarding the issue. The latest solution is installing the package from GitHub. But still, was not successful in accessing and loading dataset (gadm) from geodata. 

There might be accessibility issues from the cloud storage. I'm from SEA (PH).

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

The "geodata" package is currently working now. I suspect that there might be conflicts or restrictions with my internet provider.

Thanks!